# Expected behaviour when assigning std::string to non-terminated char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm working on C++ code developed by other people, and have found a section where a `std::string` is assigned to a `char` array which is not null-terminated. The code (simplified) is something like this:

```
char *filePath="c:\\filename.txt"; //file known to contain 20 chars per line.
int size=20;
char *buffer;
std::string bufferstr;

buffer=new char[size];
std::ifstream input(filePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
input.read(buffer,size);
bufferstr=buffer; // Assign string to non-null-terminated char array.

// Lots of other code omitted here.
input.close();
delete[] buffer;
```

I'm not surprised to find memory errors when checking the code with Dr. Memory, and have now changed this so that `buffer` is always null-terminated, but the code has had this error for about 3 years and has behaved as intended (on Windows, Linux, and Solaris) until I recently made changes in a seemingly unrelated part of the code.

My questions are:
- What is the expected behaviour when assigning a `std::string` to a non-null-terminated `char` array?
- Why would this code have started misbehaving after I made changes elsewhere?

Comment: Well, undefined behavior can _work_ still.

Comment: A good reason to always zero-set allocated memory. A good reason to never zero-set allocated memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - What is the expected behaviour when assigning a std::string to a non-null-terminated char array?

std::string will consider everything from the pointer received to the first address containing a zero value, to be part of the string. Usually, this means you either get a few garbage characters at the end of your string, or you get an application core dump, with an error like "unable to allocate " or "access violation reading ".

- Why would this code have started misbehaving after I made changes elsewhere?

Because your changes elsewhere, also changed where zeros were, in the memory adjacent to the end of your non-zero terminated buffer (this is an educated guess).

Answer (score 1):

If the char array is non-null-terminated the result is UB. What is likely to happen is that string constructor will go beyond the allocated buffer and encounter a null byte sooner or later.